# WordPress get_calendar() filter to Alter HTML Output

Tags: wordpress

By default, WordPress ships with a Calendar widget that you can use to display a calendar with the days that have posts. I would like to filter the HTML output of this widget to customize its look. Specifically, the widget displays links to previous and next months at the bottom of the calendar in the following format:

« Jan Feb »

This is the HTML I would like to change.

## What I Have Tried

If you look at `wp-includes/general-template.php` file in WordPress, there is a function called `get_calendar()` which contains the HTML I wish to change. It also has a filter hook to filter the HTML output at the bottom of the function.

If I use the following code, I can customize the output to remove the « and » and replace them with icons from FontAwesome. This works without issue.

```
function custom_calendar_output( $calendar_output ) {

    $search = array( '&laquo;', '&raquo;' );
    $replace = array( '<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i>', '<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>' );
    $cust_calendar_output = str_replace( $search, $replace, $calendar_output );

    return $cust_calendar_output;
}
add_filter( 'get_calendar', 'custom_calendar_output' );
```

## What I'm Having Trouble With

I would also like to remove the month text as well as the default arrow. So instead of having it read as: « Jan, It would just display the icon from FontAwesome. The month text changes (e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar) as the user cycles through the past months.

How can I remove both the default arrow and the month text to replace it with a custom icon?

I have read I may need to use `preg_replace` with regex but I can't seem to get this to work. I have also read that using regex uses a lot of overhead. Is there a cleaner way to do this?